# Create reusable form contact component in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm newbie at asp.net mvc, I'm trying to develop a reusable contact form component for asp.net mvc .

I have tryed to do it creating a PartialView with a form, I don't know if this is the better approach, for create a reusable component

My PartialView is

```
@model MyModel.ContactData

@using (Html.BeginForm("ContactForm", "ContactForm", FormMethod.Post)) {
<fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailAddress)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MailAddress)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</fieldset>
```

}

The problems start with the controller, the controller is a specific controller for only this partialView.

```
public class ContactFormController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactData contactData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("MessageSend");
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

My problem is in case of some of the required fields are empty, in that case the controller returns only the partial view, not returning the partival view inside its parent context. I have tryed calling the PartialView from parent View as @Html.Partial, @Html.RenderAction, @Html.RenderPartial and the same occurs.

How can I return the partial view Inside it's parent Context? I have tried with
return View(ParentViewsName, contactData) but I dislike it because on form submitting it changes the url on address bar from /Contact to /ContactForm/ContactForm.

Perphaps I'm trying to create a reusable component with a wrong approach? It's better to update with ajax only the PartialView? Alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally as Sundeep explains I have done this with ajax like this example [Partial ASP.NET MVC View submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050596/partial-asp-net-mvc-view-submit).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you wish to display status message which is a partial view after user successfully submits the form. I think tempdata will be apt for this kind of situation.

```
public class ContactFormController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactData contactData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TempData["success"] = true;             
            return RedirectToAction("parentpage");
        } 

        return View(contactData);
    }
}
```

In parent page, check whether TempData["success"] is null and display the partial view "MessageSend".

Comment: Sorry I haven't explained well, the problem is if the form is submitted when not all required fields are fill. With my current code when submitting a form with a required fill empty, it's returned only the partial view without parent's View Context.

Comment: Did you try my code. If model is invalid, it returns back to the page. If it is valid, it sets tempdata variable.

Comment: Yes I have tried, and with return View(contactData) it returns only the PartialView, losing the Parent View.

Comment: I think its not possible to do it this way. Instead you should do partial submit. Check out this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050596/partial-asp-net-mvc-view-submit.